# Unable to retrieve data from database using repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, interface, repository-pattern

I'm currently learning interfaces and repository pattern and have difficulties with it. I have domain class "VehicleMake"

```
  public class VehicleMake
{
    public VehicleMake()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<VehicleModel> VehicleModels { get; set; }
}
```

I also have an Interface "IVehicleRepository"

```
    public interface IVehicleRepository
{
    IEnumerable<VehicleMake> All { get; }
}
```

and a class "VehicleRepository" which implements that interface

```
public class VehicleRepository : IVehicleRepository
{
    private readonly VehicleDbContext _context;

    public VehicleRepository(VehicleDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<VehicleMake> All => _context.VehicleMakes;
}
```

My DbContext class is following

```
public class VehicleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public VehicleDbContext() : base("VehicleDbContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<VehicleMake> VehicleMakes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VehicleModel> VehicleModels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }

}
```

And my "VehicleController" is following

```
 public class VehicleController : Controller
{
    private readonly IVehicleRepository _vehicleRepository;

    public VehicleController()
    {

    }

    public VehicleController(IVehicleRepository vehicleRepository)
    {
        _vehicleRepository = vehicleRepository;
    }

    // GET: VehicleMakes
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_vehicleRepository.All);
    }
}
```

So the problem is that when I try in my controller to retrieve "Vehicle Makes", I get null reference exception and I don't why. Did I implemented this properly? If not, what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Remove that parameterless constructor in VehicleController and please have a test

Comment: When I remove it, I get following error: "System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Comment: Posted an answer to make your code work. Please have a look.

Comment: I added " : this(new VehicleRepository()) ", but then I got an error: There is "no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context' "

Comment: I thought, you've default constructor for VehicleRepository. I've updated code in my answer as I believe, you didn't register any dependency resolver framework in your application

Comment: thank you for your effort but still the same error, I don't have any dependency resolver framework in application

Comment: Oops ! Forgot to mention that you need to change VechileRepository to support default constructor as well. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `NullReferenceException` because it's calling your parameterless constructor where you don't have initialization of _`vehicleRepository` field. Your initialization is in constructor where you are passing `IVehicleRepository` object.

I believe, you don't have dependedency injection framework registered for correctly getting instance. So, you can simply initialize _`vehicleRepository` in default constructor :

```
public class VehicleController : Controller
{
     private readonly IVehicleRepository _vehicleRepository;

     public VehicleController()
     {
              _vehicleRepository = new VehicleRepository();
     }

     // GET: VehicleMakes
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
          return View(_vehicleRepository.All);
     }
}
```

Change your VehicleRepository to support default constructor in following way :

```
public class VehicleRepository : IVehicleRepository
{
    private readonly VehicleDbContext _context;
    public VehicleRepository() : this(new VehicleDbContext())
    {
    }
    public VehicleRepository(VehicleDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<VehicleMake> All => _context.VehicleMakes;
}
```